# Inno script download file from internet Async

Tags: dll, inno-setup, pascal

how I can download the file from internet in Inno. but please keep in mind that I want the async download. In otherwords I would like the download starts at the background and UI would be responsive.

As far as I know, it doesn't seems that there is any method to do download async in inno script as it doesn't support theads and timer.

could you help me with this or let me know any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure whether that can be done. You might be able to write an extension DLL with two functions:

One that spawns a new thread for the download (passing the download URL and a temporary file name) and another one that you can call regularly to check whether the download is finished or an error occurred.

You'd then call the first function when your setup starts (make sure to not start the download when uninstalling). Call the second method when you require the downloaded file. At some point you'll need to wait for the download to be finished.

Also, thinking about it, another function to cancel the download thread would be useful so you can react to the setup being cancelled.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957070/problem-calling-dll-function-with-parameter-in-inno-setup) to find hints on how to call a function in a DLL from Pascal Script.

**EDIT**
To make more clear what I'd expect the functions to do, I'm trying to make up some pseudo-code (may look a bit like C# ;-) ):

```
// This is a global variable for the thread
Thread globalDownloadThread = null;
bool threadFinished = false;
bool threadShouldFinish = false;

void StartDownload(string url, string outputFile)
{
   globalDownloadThread = new Thread(DownloadThreadMethod);
   globalDownloadThread.Start(url, outputFile);
}

void DownloadThreadMethod(string url, string outputFile)
{
   bool downloadComplete = false;
   bool downloadErrors = false;

   while (!threadShouldFinish && !downloadComplete && !downloadErrors)
   {
       // Download a bit of the file
       // Save to the output file

       // Store errors
       if (error)
          downloadErrors = true;
       else if (noMoreBytesToDownload)
          // When we're done...
          downloadComplete = true;
   }

   threadFinished = true;
 }

 void CancelThread()
 {
   threadShouldFinish = true;
   globalDownloadThread.Join(); // Wait for thread to finish!
 }

 bool IsThreadDone()
 {
   return threadFinished;
 }
```

In Inno Setup, call the `StartDownload` method first. If the setup is cancelled after `StartDownload` was called (only then there's a thread!), call `CancelThread`.

At the point where you need to make sure that the file was downloaded, repeatedly call `IsThreadDone` until it returns true.

Of course, this has to be spiced up with locking mechanisms and there's no real error reporting here, but I hope you get the picture of what I had in mind.

**EDIT 2**
I'll translate some of my pseudo-code into C++ from what you've posted in the comments.

```
HANDLE hThread = 0;
DWORD dwThreadId = 0;
DWORD dwThreadResult = 0;

extern "C" bool _declspec(dllexport) downloadfile(TCHAR *url, TCHAR *dest) 
{ 
    DOWNLOADPARAM *obj = new DOWNLOADPARAM(); 
    obj->szURL = url; 
    obj->szFilePath = dest; 

    if ((hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, inetTransfer, (LPVOID)obj, 0,&dwThreadId)) == NULL) 
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}

extern "C" bool _declspec(dllexport) isThreadDone() 
{ 
    DWORD res = WaitForSingleObject(hThread, 10);
    if (res == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
        return TRUE;

    // Set error flag depending on other values of res
    dwThreadResult = res;
    return FALSE;
}

extern "C" DWORD _declspec(dllexport) isThreadErrored()
{
    return dwThreadResult;
}
```

It does not matter whether there's a `while` loop in your `inetTransfer` function or not - you will most probably even require a loop of some kind! The `downloadfile` function creates the thread and returns. The other functions are used to check whether the thread has successfully ended.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the valuable information, can you please let layout an algorithm or code snippet to support the above mentioned way. I know how to write the extension dll, infact I had created the dll and used it in the inno setup before. so I know how to do that. can you share or write the code snippet in C++ which depicts the above scenario more clearly. any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, I'm not that much of a C++ guy, so I hope that some pseudo-code is OK. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Or you might go for Deanna's answer... ;-)

Comment: Deanna solution is the blocking call for internet file download.but i want to achieve async download (non blocking). thank you for the pseudo code but as far I see that, the while loop in the thread is again blocking in the context that it is in the dll function and I am calling it from the inno setup. let me explain it as below. In the inno setup i will call the download function from the c++ extension dll. and the dll function creates a thread to download the file from the internet as you have shown in the above code. but the while loop in the thread block the call. I need non blocking sol.

Comment: No, the call will *not block* - the *thread* will run until the download is finished. But as a new parallel processing (=> thread) is started in the function you will call from InnoSetup, the function will return immediately after starting the thread - that's what multi-threading is all about :-)

Comment: this is code snippet in the dll i am using, but this call is blocking extern "C" 
void  __declspec(dllexport)   downloadfile(TCHAR *url, TCHAR *dest)
{
 Mutex mutex_;

 DWORD dwThreadId;
 DOWNLOADPARAM *obj = new DOWNLOADPARAM();
 obj->szURL  = url;
 obj->szFilePath = dest;

    
 if((hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, inetTransfer, (LPVOID)obj, 0,&dwThreadId)) != NULL)
 {
 }

 WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);
}

Comment: As the thread not returned to the caller (the inno setup) because of the while loop, the function will not return immediately, it will block the call. the reason is that I am calling the dll function which in turns create the thread to do download file from the internet. let me know, i can send you the code to check it.

Comment: You are wrong. The reason *your* implementation blocks is the call to `WaitForSingleObject`. Remove this and your implementation won't block either. My implementation would *not block*, as I am *not waiting* for the thread to finish in the function that's being called from InnoSetup. The `while` loop blocks the thread (which is desired), but the thread is running independently. So again: The `StartDownload` function starts the thread and returns. The thread method runs in a while loop until everything is downloaded, but in the background without blocking InnoSetup.

Comment: The problem is not my demo code not working, the problem is that your code doesn't do the same thing I'm suggesting in my demo code :-) I'm again changing my answer a little...

Answer (score 2):

Look at [InnoTools Downloader](http://www.sherlocksoftware.org/page.php?id=50). It was written for exactly this purpose and gives download progress, etc..

Comment: this downloader block the call, i need non blocking function for internet download.

Comment: For what reason? the installer can't do much else bar keep the UI responsive.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like InnoTools Downloader wasn't updated in a long time and doesn't support UNICODE...

There is another project that looks promissing: https://bitbucket.org/mitrich_k/inno-download-plugin
It was updated on Dec2016 and supports ANSI & UNICODE versions of InnoSetup.
It has examples and the documentation is OK, it even supports multiple languages, like *Spanish, Chinesse...*